# How to solve "Exception evaluating SpringEL expression" in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am using Microsoft SQL with my Spring boot application. I have everything figured out and now I am trying to pass data from my SQL database to my front-end. However, when I pass the information via `thymeleaf` it does not work. I have a app repository as well as a DTO class that actually passes the data. Though I keep getting the same error. Sorry to bombard everyone with so much code, but I have been trying to figure a solution for a while and still can't think of a way to solve it. I believe it has to do with the TestApp class but not sure where.

**Error:**

```
    org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'dtoTiername' cannot be found on object of type 'com.John.model.TestApp' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

**App Repository:**

```
        @Query("SELECT new com.John.model.TestApp(t.tiername, t.system) FROM AppSelectorTier t")
        List<TestApp>getServerInfo();
```

**Service Layer:**

```
    public List<TestApp> getServerInfo() {
                List<TestApp> myList = appRepository.getServerInfo();
                System.out.println(myList.size());
                return myList;
            }
```

**Controller:**

```
        @RequestMapping("/edit")
        public ModelAndView editTab(Model model) {

            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            List<TestApp>ary4 = new ArrayList<TestApp>();
            try {
                System.out.println("Hello Code");
                ary4 = joinQueryService.getServerInfo();
                modelAndView.setViewName("create");             

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                modelAndView.setViewName("test");           
            }
            modelAndView.addObject("ary4",ary4);
            return modelAndView;                                
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Tiername</th>
                      <th>System</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                 <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="ary4 : ${ary4}">
                        <td th:text="${ary4.dtoTiername}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${ary4.dtoSystem}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

               </table>
```

**TestApp:**

```
package com.John.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

public class TestApp implements java.io.Serializable  {

    private String dtoTiername;
    private String dtoSystem;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    //Constructor
    public TestApp(String dtoTiername, String dtoSystem) {
        super();
        this.dtoTiername = dtoTiername;
        this.dtoSystem = dtoSystem;
    }

    //Default Constructor
    public TestApp() {

    }



    //Getter
    public String getName() {
        return dtoTiername;
    }

    public String getSystem() {
        return dtoSystem;
    }


    //Setter
    public void setName(String dtoTiername) {
        this.dtoTiername = dtoTiername;
    }


    public void setSystem(String dtoSystem) {
        this.dtoSystem = dtoSystem;
    }

}
```

**Entity:**

```
package com.John.model;

import java.util.*;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tier")
public class AppSelectorTier implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tiername")
    private String tiername;

    @Column(name = "system")
    private String system;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    //Constructor
    public AppSelectorTier(String tiername, String system) {
        super();
        this.tiername = tiername;
        this.system = system;
    }

    //Default Constructor
    public AppSelectorTier() {

    }



    //Getter
    public String getName() {
        return tiername;
    }

    public String getSystem() {
        return system;
    }


    //Setter
    public void setName(String tiername) {
        this.tiername = tiername;
    }


    public void setSystem(String system) {
        this.system = system;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your _property_ name is `name`, not `dtoTiername`. Properties are defined by getters and setters, not the backing fields.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are mapped by getters and setters so you can do either of these

**First:**

keep getter setter align to variable Name

```
public class TestApp implements java.io.Serializable  {

    private String dtoTiername;
    private String dtoSystem;

    public String getDtoTiername() {
        return dtoTiername;
    }
    public void setDtoTiername(String dtoTiername) {
        this.dtoTiername = dtoTiername;
    }
    public String getDtoSystem() {
        return dtoSystem;
    }
    public void setDtoSystem(String dtoSystem) {
        this.dtoSystem = dtoSystem;
    }

}
```

**Second:**

Change JSP variable to

```
<tr th:each="ary4 : ${ary4}">
    <td th:text="${ary4.name}"></td>
    <td th:text="${ary4.system}"></td>
</tr>
```